# Sharepoint 2019 - Form creation without PowerApps or Flow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, forms-services

We are currently in the process of moving to SP 2019 on premise. We are not licensed for Office 365 and will not be for another two years.

I believe without the licensing we cannot use PowerApps or Flow. Can anyone confirm this?

If this is the case - does anyone have a recommendation for form building - preferably a free or low cost option? We currently use InfoPath for form building which I know will be phased out completely by 2026.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. To work with MS flow and Power Apps, users need to buy licenses separately as described here for [MS flow pricing](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/), [PowerApps pricing](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/)

For InfoPath alternatives, I would suggest you use PowerApps and Microsoft Flow. Otherwise, you could use some third party tools for form building. Refer to here for more:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/InfoPath-alternative/m-p/83803

Comment: Thanks Michael - the link is really useful.